# Can an Artificer cast V,S spells with no free hand

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components, artificer, spellcasting-focus

Just seeking to clear up a bit of confusion. There seems to be a lot of points and counter points floating around so I will start at the beginning.

As I understand it a Artificer (RAW but perhaps not RAI) can cast V,S,M and V,S spells with both hands full. Let's assume one is a shield and one is a sword and at least one item is infused so as to act as his spell casting focus.

**First, can they cast a V,S,M spell with no free hand?**

See [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46201/how-do-foci-and-somaticmaterial-components-interact-when-it-comes-to-occupying) highly upvoted thread for what seems to be a clear confirmation of this. Additionally the [official ruling](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/rules-spellcasting) from Sage Advice is:

> Another example: a cleric’s holy symbol is emblazoned on her shield. She likes to wade into melee combat with a mace in one hand and a shield in the other. She uses the holy symbol as her spellcasting focus, so she needs to have the shield in hand when she casts a cleric spell that has a material component. If the spell, such as aid, also has a somatic component, she can perform that component with the shield hand and keep holding the mace in the other.

**Second, can they cast V,S spells with no free hand?**

This part seems easy. The answer is no. Nothing Material and hence no use of the arcane focus. However, if you read the Artificer Spellcasting section (emphasis added):

> **Tools Required**
> You produce your artificer spell effects through your tools. You must have a spellcasting focus—specifically thieves’ tools or some kind of artisan’s tool—in hand when you cast any spell with this Spellcasting feature *(meaning the spell has an ‘M’ component when you cast it)*. You must be proficient with the tool to use it in this way. See chapter 5, “Equipment,” in the Player’s Handbook for descriptions of these tools.

Since it clearly states any spell you cast has an 'M'. If the first is true and you can cast V,S,M with no free hand, then it goes to assume you can cast all spells as such.

Comment: I think the question (and answers) need to take into consideration the sub-class of Artificer. For instance, most need their tool (thieves' tools, alchemist tools, etc), but the Armorer is different. At 3rd level, _"You can use the arcane armor as a spellcasting focus for your artificer spells."_. Literally, your hands (gauntlets) become a focus meaning there is nothing to hold.

Comment: All subclasses can use 'infusions' as an arcane focus. And armor or shield can be infused if you take Enhanced Defense. But you do make a good point, considering some subclasses require or allow different focus's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### One Hand for Both S and M Components

You quote part of the rules related to spellcasting:

> A spellcaster must have a free hand to access a spell's material components - or to hold a focus - but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform Somatic components.

That means that the hand holding your focus can also perform the somatic components, which for [most artificers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#ClassFeatures) is their tools or infused item:

> #### Tools Required
>
> You produce your artificer spell effects through your tools. You must have a spellcasting focus—specifically thieves’ tools or some kind of artisan’s tool—in hand when you cast any spell with this Spellcasting feature **(meaning the spell has an ‘M’ component when you cast it)**...
>
> After you gain the Infuse Item feature at 2nd level, you can also use any item bearing one of your infusions as a spellcasting focus.

### No VS without M

All spells a artificer cast require a Material component. The Spell Casting feature quoted and linked above contains the following line (form the newest errata):

> (meaning the spell has an ‘M’ component when you cast it)

Which means: **"yes", in practice means you can cast spells that *would otherwise* be VS with the hand holding your tools or an infused weapon** and you don't need a free hand; but only because they also require the Material component for the Artificer class.

Answer (score 11):

### There are no V,S artificer spells

As you've observed, the artificer's Spellcasting feature specifies that **all artificer spells have a material component**. In fact, the parenthetical explaining this was added in an [erratum](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/ERftLW-Errata.pdf) specifically to make this fact unambiguous. Hence, all the rules for casting spells with a material component apply to every artificer spell you cast, including the rule that M and S components for a spell can be provided with the same hand.

So technically, the answer is no, an artificer cannot cast a V,S spell with no free hand, or with a free hand, or at all, because they don't have any V,S spells.